# Getting Item after the one i select when creating context menu on Android

Tags: android, listview, realm, contextmenu

Basically I have an activity which displays a listview, and it has a context menu. The problem is I'm getting a context menu for the item after the one i selected, which means if I long click item 1, I get a context menu for item 2, and if I long click the last item, the app crashes because it's trying to fetch an item that doesn't even exist. The logcat throws this error when long clicking the second item in a 2 item list:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 2 > 2
```

I don't think i'm doing something different from any of the other listviews in my app, so this is really strange for me.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RealmChangeListener<RealmList<Detail>>{

        private ListView listViewDetails;
        private Realm realm;
        private RealmList<Detail> details;
        private Routine routine;
        private DetailsAdapter adapter;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            routine = realm.where(Routine.class).equalTo("id",id).findFirst();
            details = routine.getDetails();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(routine.getName());

            details.addChangeListener(this);

            adapter = new DetailsAdapter(this,details,R.layout.detail_item);
            listViewDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetails);

            listViewDetails.setAdapter(adapter);

            registerForContextMenu(listViewDetails);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmList<Detail> element) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        menu.setHeaderTitle(details.get(info.position).getExercise());
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
        MenuItem itemDelete = menu.findItem(R.id.itemDelete);
        MenuItem itemEdit = menu.findItem(R.id.itemEdit);
        itemDelete.setTitle(R.string.delete);
        itemEdit.setTitle(R.string.edit);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.itemDelete:
                deleteDialog(details.get(info.position));
                return true;

            case R.id.itemEdit:
                editDialog(details.get(info.position));
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

DetailsAdapter:

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Detail> list;
    private int layout;
    private Context context;

    public DetailsAdapter(Context context, List<Detail> list, int layout){

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.layout = layout;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder vh;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout,parent,false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.textViewExercise = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewExercise);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Detail detail = list.get(position);

        vh.textViewExercise.setText(detail.getExercise());

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        public TextView textViewExercise;

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please publish code of the adapter?

Comment: @Buckstabue sure, sorry it wasn't there. Check the edited answer.

Comment: What version of Realm is this? Any reason why you aren't using `RealmBaseAdapter` from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters ? Although my guess is that you'll need to somehow invalidate the context menu when content changes.

Comment: I suspect that's because you just return position in `getItemId()` method. Please try to return something like `list.get(position).getId()` or NO_ID